# How to increase distance between PHY and RJ45 for GbE?

Tags: ethernet

The PHY I will be using is unfortunately far away from the front panel RJ45 jack (with integrated magnetics). Approximately 13 inches. This is over the maximum recommended distance between the PHY and the magnetics. Is there some sort of a redriver/buffer/equalizer IC that i can use to boost this signal midway?

Answer (score 3):

Fit a plain RJ45 in the front panel and move the jack with the magnetics back where it needs to be...